# AWS Lambda .NET Core ENV variables naming

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda

I have a .NET Core AWS Lambda function and I need to specify
log level for specific classes or namespaces and I need to do it via Environment Variable: `Logging__LogLevel__Out.Internal.Class` with Value `debug`

However, I am getting an validation error:

`The key must start with a letter and can only contain letters, numbers, and underscores.`

Is there any workaroung?

Thanks

Comment: Can class / package names contain underscores? If not then just replace the dots with underscores.

Comment: namespace contains dots of course

Comment: I mean it the other way around, replace it with underscores in the environment variable and when reading from the env variable, convert it. Store `Logging__LogLevel__Out_Internal_Class=debug` - this can trivially be split into `Internal_Class` which can then be transformed to `Internal.Class` which should uniquely identify the class you want to configure.

Comment: yes sir, I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: @luk2302 First of all, how can so many Lukes be chatting about this. Anyway... replacing the underscores manually isn't much use when you want to use the built in Logging stuff to control log output...? Such as ConfigurationBuilder

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can load the configuration from a service like AWS Parameter Store. That way you can store your application configuration as a string (or JSON if you multiple properties) and retrieve it once in your function initialization. It will have a small impact on cold start performance, but it will be negligible.

The added benefit of this, is that you can update your configuration without changing your function code.

If you're using standard parameters and standard throughput it's also completely free.

https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/pricing/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html
https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/aws-parameter-store/

There's also AWS AppConfig if you want a slightly more advanced use case (CICD for your configuration, feature flags) but for simple use cases parameter store is great.